# C program - exer1.c:39: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘&’ token

Tags: c

I am a beginner C programmer. I was trying to write a program using pointer but got stuck here. i don't see anything obvious (unless I am too careless to spot) but its still throwing above error during compilation.
Thanks in advance.

Below is the program, I am trying to compile: A program which accepts an amount (dollar) and tells us how many 20s, 10s, 5s and 1s will be sum up to that amount.

```
int main (void)
{

   int dollar, tw, tn, fv, on;

   printf ("Enter amount to change:\n");
   scanf ("%d", &dollar);

   tw = (dollar / 20);
   dollar %= 20;

   tn = (dollar / 10);
   dollar %= 10;

   fv = (dollar / 5);
   dollar %= 5;

   on = dollar;

    /* Define Function */

     void pay_amount (int dollars, int *twenties, int *tens, int *fives, int *ones)
     {
      printf ("Amount entered: %d\n", dollars);
      printf ("Change:\n");
      printf ("Twenties  %d", *twenties);
      printf ("Tens  %d", *tens);
      printf ("Fives  %d", *fives);
      printf ("Ones  %d", *ones);
     }

     /* call function */

     void pay_amount (dollar, &tw, &tn , &fv , &on);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't define a function inside another function. (And there's no real reason to use pointers here either.) And to call a function, you use `pay_amount (dollar, &tw, &tn , &fv , &on);`, not `void pay_amount (dollar, &tw, &tn , &fv , &on);`.

Comment: That isn't how you call a function. Find a good book and it will explain things. Just trying things out with C generally leads to bad results.

Comment: Thanks so much for your suggestions. Yes I did made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define a function inside an other.
Here is a fix code :

```
#include<stdio.h>

/* Define Function */
void pay_amount (int dollars, int *twenties, int *tens, int *fives, int *ones)
{
    printf ("Amount entered: %d\n", dollars);
    printf ("Change:\n");
    printf ("Twenties  %d", *twenties);
    printf ("Tens  %d", *tens);
    printf ("Fives  %d", *fives);
    printf ("Ones  %d", *ones);
}

int main (void)
{

   int dollar, tw, tn, fv, on;

   printf ("Enter amount to change:\n");
   scanf ("%d", &dollar);

   tw = (dollar / 20);
   dollar %= 20;

   tn = (dollar / 10);
   dollar %= 10;

   fv = (dollar / 5);
   dollar %= 5;

   on = dollar;

     /* call function */

     pay_amount (dollar, &tw, &tn , &fv , &on);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I did compile the code you modified for me and needless to say it compiled successfully. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As the others said:

- you can't define a function in a function.
- you can define the full function with body above main,
  Or define the prototype at the top so that main will know it exists:
  void pay_amount (int dollars, int *twen twenties, int *tens, int *fives, int *ones);
  And the full function as you have it written below main.
- you don't specify the return type in your function call you either assign it to a variable or just call it with no assignment.  Even if you have a return type for a function you don't HAVE to assign it to a variable.  You're passing in pointers which give the function side effects.  You could return an int or other type to return error messages if you wanted to do error checking in the function and check the return value from the call to make sure everything went expected.

Comment: Thanks for writing such a fine explanation. I do realize my mistake.